# how to find HOST_NAME() Values page of the New Subscription Wizard

Tags: sql-server, replication, subscription

i want to Overriding the HOST_NAME() Value for Parameterized row filters in sql server data replication . in this link http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa337384.aspx and this one http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms152478%28v=sql.110%29.aspx says i must Override HOST_NAME() Value in the HOST_NAME() Values page of the New Subscription Wizard , but i cant find this page when i create a new subscription, even for merge publication . plz help me thank...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will only see the ***HOST_NAME Values*** page in the New Subscription Wizard if the publication you are subscribing to contains articles with parameterized row filters using the HOST_NAME() function.

Please verify your publication contains articles with parameterized row filters using the HOST_NAME() function.

Comment: i am a beginner can u pleas give me more explain ... how can i do that or give me an example ?? thanks

Comment: how can i create a publication with a parameterized row filter